# Set up a cron job using values from a database in a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cron

I have a servlet in which I query DB2 to get `due_dates`, which I need to send reminder emails to customers.

I know how to set up cron jobs for weekly or daily tasks with the standalone java class but I do not know how to take the output of a query and use it to set up a job in the cron scheduler.

How can I schedule a cron job using those `due_dates` values ?

Answer (score 0):

Youd be better of having the cron run every day/12 hours or whatever and send any emails due then rather than trying to schedule another cron